# What is the best way to write if-then-else for a large data set in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to write conditional statements for a large data set in JavaScript. The goal is to calculate Calorie (results) intake based on age and lifestyle.

Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
    <label>Enter Age (2 to 100)</label>
    <input id="getAge" type="text" placeholder="" />
    <label>Enter 1 for Sedentary, 2 for Moderate, 3 for Active</label>
    <input id="getLifeStyle" type="text" placeholder="" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let age, lifestyle, calorie;

age = document.getElementById("getAge").value
lifestyle = document.getElementById("getLifeStyle").value

// two
if (age==2) {
 if (lifestyle==1) {
   calorie=1000
  }
 if (lifestyle==2) {
   calorie=2000
 }
 ....
 // three
 else if (age==3) {
  if (lifestyle==1) {
   calorie=1000
  }
 if (lifestyle==2) {
   calorie=2000
 }....
 // four...and so, until 100

 // Show calorie
 console.log("Calorie: "+calorie)
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Basically repeat the above several times. I am not an expert in JavaScript. While the above is working fine to get the results, I don't think this may be the most efficient way to write if-then-else. Are there any other **efficient** options in JavaScript to do this?

Comment: Seems like this was asked today. On same recommendation, an "array" either retrieved by AJAX, or embedded in same script, would be two-dimensional, where `data[0][0]` is where person is an infant at just before second of birth on first dimension, and 2nd dimension is calorie intake, that being "1,000" if `data[0][0] == 1000`. But of course make first dimension on years.

Comment: There's no discernible pattern to that table so an algorithm doesn't seem possible, nor does control flow statements (ie `if`, `if else`) seem practical either. Yeah, a 2D array is probably the best solution. Or find a better source of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested object indexed by age, then indexed by lifestyle would work.

```
const calorieData = {
  2: {
    1: 1000,
    2: 2000,
  },
  3: {
    1: 1000,
    2: 2000,
  }
};

// ...

const calories = calorieData[age][lifestyle];
```

A DRY-er version would use arrays instead, but it could require slightly more confusing code due to 0-based indicies.

```
const calorieData = [
  // omit index 0
  ,
  // omit index 1
  ,
  [1000, 2000],
  [1000, 2000],
  // ...
];

// ...

// because lifestyle is 1-indexed
const calories = calorieData[age][lifestyle - 1];
```

Comment: In the first solution (nested object), in case ages 18, 19, 20 have the same calories data, is there an easier way to write that (a shorter form, spread operator, etc)?

Comment: If there are a sufficient number of such repeating sequences, you could create *another* structure too, one that associates an index or keyword to a calorie sequence. Eg `{ normal: [1000, 2000] }` and then map each age to a sequence identifier instead of to an array. But while that would be less repetitive, it'd be a lot harder to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const LIFE_STYLE = {
  SEDENTARY: '1',
  MODERATE: '2',
  ACTIVE: '3'
}
const data = [
  { age: 2, lifeStyle: LIFE_STYLE.SEDENTARY, calories: 1000 },
  { age: 3, lifeStyle: LIFE_STYLE.SEDENTARY, calories: 1000 }
]

const getCaloryData = (age, lifestyle) => {
  const entry = data.find(entry => entry.age === age && entry.lifeStyle === lifestyle)
  return entry ? entry.calories : undefined;
}
```

The complexity is higher but the readability is better.

Answer (score 0):

the best & shortest alternative way for that is using ternary operator

```
// two
{age == 2 && lifestyle == 1 && calorie = 1000}
{age == 2 && lifestyle == 2 && calorie = 2000}
//three
{age == 3 && lifestyle == 1 && calorie = 1000}
{age == 3 && lifestyle == 2 && calorie = 2000}
// until 100
```

Comment: Embedding "changeable data" in the source code has its obvious execution wise performance levels. But same embedding makes it harder to change the values, especially if the person to change these values does not know the programming languages.